# Is it permissible to only wash the top of the feet for wudu while not wearing socks or shoes?

Tags: wudu

I have been washing only the top of my feet for the last part of wudu, while not wearing socks or shoes as I thought this was the way to do wudu, is it wrong?

Comment: `Wash feet three times, begin with right foot from tip of toenail to just above ankle.`

Comment: Check this question/answer out: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2962/what-is-the-correct-way-to-wash-the-feets-when-performing-wudu?rq=1

Comment: AFAIK there's no single scholar who said that it is sufficient washing a part of the feet. And feet "cleaning" is an essential part of wudu'.